# Unable to Login in Ubuntu Server Through SSH Due to Changed Home Directory Permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, server, vps

I have a remote headless Ubuntu 14.04 VPS (Linode) & I've been using it since last 3 years without any issues by SSHing from my local terminal. Suddenly today when I tried to SSH, I received following warning and after fallback from public key I was asked for the password. After entering the password, I was immediately logged out with following error:

```
~> ssh <user>@<server>.com -p 2292
<user>@<server>.com's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-x86_64-linode63 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Fri Feb 19 17:51:39 2016 from 10.49.20.22
Could not chdir to home directory /home/<user>: Permission denied
/bin/bash: Permission denied
Connection to <server>.com closed.
```

Before enabling the login by public key, I had disabled the root login for security purposes & there's just one user on the server apart from root, which is not able to log in now, due to some permission issue, caused unexpectedly without my doing.

Kindly suggest what can be done here to gain access again ?

Here's the verbose output of SSH

```
~> ssh -v x@cb.com -p 2359
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to cb.com [66.228.60.78] port 2359.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/st/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/st/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/st/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/st/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/st/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/st/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/st/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/st/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to cb.com:2256 as 'x'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:C4FE2EmPxxAYBue706iHjHJwYxsFgwr+b8J/KSK6Y0g
debug1: Host '[cb.com]:2256' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/st/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/st/.ssh/bitbucket
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/st/.ssh/linode
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/st/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/st/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/st/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/st/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
x@cb.com's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to cb.com ([66.228.60.78]:2256).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-x86_64-linode63 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Fri Feb 19 18:18:23 2016 from 103.249.240.242
Could not chdir to home directory /home/x: Permission denied
/bin/bash: Permission denied
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to cb.com closed.
Transferred: sent 4160, received 3064 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 7925.5, received 5837.4
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: If you have removed execute permission from root folder, then I suppose nothing can be done.

Comment: But I haven't. Haven't touched a thing from a long time. Especially the permissions. The error does make it seem like I have changed my own user's home directory's permission, but I haven't. And especially not root's.

Comment: Your best shot is to try with root credentials and check the permissions

Comment: Ya, that would have solved the problem, if l hadn't disabled root login with password.

Comment: Root login was disabled only for remote SSH access. It worked when I tried to login through web-console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best and fastest way - is to login via ip-kvm or web-console and login directly, then check all stuff.

Comment: I tried logging in through Linode's web console (LISH). Even LISH takes me till the login screen & from there when I enter the correct password, same thing happens

Comment: Can you edit grub's boot menu? If so, then add `single init=/bin/bash` to linux kernel arguments. Then remount / as rw, and you're in system.

Comment: Finally, it's done. I used linode web interface to reset its password, then logged in through Graphical Web Console, there was some issue with the filesystem, as it was mounting in read-only mode everytime. Forced a fsck & restarted. Then created another user & now I can SSH. Permissions on the previous user seemed all normal, don't know why it wasn't working but since I have a new functioning sudoer, it doesn't matter.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction.